# Find-or-insert with only one lookup in C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, lookup

I'm a former C++/STL programmer trying to code a fast marching algorithm using C#/.NET technology...

I'm searching for an equivalent of STL method `map::insert` that insert a value at given key if not exists, else returns an iterator to the existing key-value pair.

The only way I found does this with two lookups: one inside `TryGetValue` and another one in `Add` method:

```
List<Point> list;
if (!_dictionary.TryGetValue (pcost, out list))
{
    list = new List<Point>();
    dictionary.Add (pcost, list);
}
list.Add(new Point { X = n.x, Y = n.y });
```

Is there something that explains why this is not possible using .NET containers? Or did I missed some point?

Comment: Are you sure it does two lookups even in production code?

Comment: Does the dual look up really matter? The difference in time is marginal.

Comment: @Chris: what? you don't have any benchmark to back that up, let alone a benchmark relevant to the OP's usage patterns ;) -- I can show you code where it matters (oh wait, _I can't_ for legal reasons...)

Comment: In fact, I didn't benchmark yet : maybe the cli machine caches the last result to be used as a hint for next lookup, which could suppress the cost of the Add operation.

Answer (score 12):

You can just assign your value in the following way:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
dict[2] = 11;
```

if value with key 2 does not exist - it will be added and otherwise it will be just overriden.

Dictionary does not have method GetOrAdd, but ConcurrentDictionary from C# 4.0 does:

```
var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
dict[2] = 10;
int a = dict.GetOrAdd(2, 11);// a == 10
```

Comment: @gorik using Dictionary like you showed will throw an exception if the key does not exist

Comment: @amichai gerstl no, please try it out

Comment: The first one is "AddorUpdate". +1 for "GetOrAdd".

Comment: This does not solve the problem, as in my case, the value of the dictionary is a list, and I don't want to lose the elements which have been already added for a particular key.

Answer (score 2):

The standard generic dictionary does not support this, the 2 lookups are required. Though the cost of the look ups are normally negligible so this isn't a problem, and you can often get better results tuning other parts of the system rather than trying to micro-optimise dictionary lookups.

The only dictionary that comes with .net that supports this that I know of is [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287189.aspx) with the method [GetOrAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677.aspx). Though now you're paying the cost of synchronization instead.

Comment: false, check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16193323/893406 only one lookup.

Comment: @v.oddou the call to `dict.Add` internally performs a look up, hence the 2 look ups. One look up by TryGetValue, and one by Add.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there something that explains why
>   this is not possible using .NET
>   containers ?

Without knowing the real background, I assume it is because of simplicity of the Dictionary. There are only the basic, easy to understand functions: `Add`, `Remove` a.s.o., while the index operator does a little bit of magic, which was probably assumed to be intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, there isn't one in bcl's implementation. The closest alternative is doing two lookups, but one can have a generic extension method to make it easy, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705950/combined-check-add-or-fetch-from-dictionary)

```
public static T GetOrAdd<S, T>(this IDictionary<S, T> dict, S key, 
                               Func<T> valueCreator)
{
    T value;
    return dict.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? value : dict[key] = valueCreator();
}
```

But there is [C5's implementation](https://github.com/sestoft/C5/blob/master/C5/Dictionaries.cs) which does this out of the box. The method definition looks like this:

```
public virtual bool FindOrAdd(K key, ref V value)
{

}
```

I don't know why they don't accept a `Func<V>` instead of `V` to defer object creation. C5 has a lot of nice similar tricks, for eg,

```
public virtual bool Remove(K key, out V value)

public virtual bool Update(K key, V value, out V oldvalue)

public virtual bool UpdateOrAdd(K key, V value, out V oldvalue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from .NET 6, it is now possible to implement a `GetOrAdd` extension method for the [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) class that takes a `key` and a `valueFactory`, and hashes the key only once. The new API is the [`CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.getvaluereforadddefault) method, with this signature:

```
// Gets a reference to a TValue in the specified dictionary, adding a new entry
// with a default value if the key does not exist.
public static ref TValue? GetValueRefOrAddDefault<TKey,TValue> (
    Dictionary<TKey,TValue> dictionary, TKey key, out bool exists);
```

This is a [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#reference-return-values) returning method. It can be used to implement the `GetOrAdd` like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds a key/value pair to the dictionary by using the specified function
/// if the key does not already exist. Returns the new value, or the
/// existing value if the key exists.
/// </summary>
public static TValue GetOrAdd<TKey, TValue>(
    this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
    TKey key,
    Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(dictionary);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(valueFactory);

    ref TValue value = ref CollectionsMarshal
        .GetValueRefOrAddDefault(dictionary, key, out bool exists);
    if (!exists)
    {
        try { value = valueFactory(key); }
        catch { dictionary.Remove(key); throw; }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Usage example:

```
List<Point> list = dictionary.GetOrAdd(pcost, key => new List<Point>());
list.Add(new Point { X = n.x, Y = n.y });
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DvaWw7), featuring also an overload with generic parameter `TArg`.

The try/catch in the implementation is required in order to remove the empty entry, in case the `valueFactory` throws an exception. Otherwise the exception would leave the dictionary in a corrupted state (containing a key with a `default` value).

Btw [a proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/15059) to add this method in the standard .NET libraries has been submitted on GitHub, but it didn't generate enough traction and it was closed.

Answer (score -1):

Old question, but I may have just stumbled across an acceptable solution. I use a combination of TryGetValue, ternary operator and index assignment.

```cs
var thing = _dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var existing) ? existing : _dictionary[key] = new Thing();
```

I have written a small example for that.

```cs
class Program
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> _translations
        = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "en", "Hello world!" } };

    private static string AddOrGetTranslation(string locale, string defaultText)
        => _translations.TryGetValue(locale, out var existingTranslation)
            ? existingTranslation
            : _translations[locale] = defaultText;

    static void Main()
    {
        var defaultText = "#hello world#";

        Console.WriteLine(AddOrGetTranslation("en", defaultText)); // -> Hello world!

        Console.WriteLine(AddOrGetTranslation("de", defaultText)); // -> #hello world#
        Console.WriteLine(AddOrGetTranslation("de", "differentDefaultText")); // -> #hello world#

        _translations["de"] = "Hallo Welt!";
        Console.WriteLine(AddOrGetTranslation("de", defaultText)); // -> Hallo Welt!
    }
}
```

EDIT: ⚠️ There is an uncertainty of this solution. See comments on the solution.

Comment: This solution still uses two lookups, or I missed something?

Comment: I'm really unsure about that. 
I have assumed so far that an assignment via the indexer, no prior lookup is necessary.

I would have to search in the Dictionary source in advance...

Answer (score -3):

You can create extension method for that:

```
IDictionary<string, Point> _dictionary = GetDictionary();
_dictionary.GetOrAdd( "asdf" ).Add( new Point(14, 15) );

// ... elsewhere ...
public static class DictionaryExtensions {
    public static List<TValue> GetOrAdd<TKey, TValue>( this IDictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> self, TKey key ) {
        List<TValue> result;
        self.TryGetValue( key, out result );
        if ( null == result ) {
            // the key value can be set to the null
            result = new List<TValue>();
            self[key] = result;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are assuming TValue is a reference type there, you should be checking the return value of TryGetValue instead.

Comment: This is the same code as in the question only now made an extension. How does this help? Still 2 calls, trygetvalue and the add.

Comment: @PoweRoy: to be fair, the performance will have been impacted (just not in the right direction)

Comment: @PowerRoy: This is only way, how to achieve it with Dictionary<TKey, TValue>. If you want, you can do your own implementation of IDictionary<TKey, TValue> and implement more efficient way.

Comment: TryGetValue has a return value. checking result for null is invalid, you may have added null as a value.

Comment: @Stefan Steinegger: But if I want add value into list and the value is NULL, its the same situation as the the value is not added = adding value will cause exception.

Comment: Adding null as value does not cause an exception, only using null as a key. However, TryGetValue has a return value which must be evaluated to make the code reliable.

Comment: @Stafen Steinegger: But adding value into null List<Point> does. That's the point!