# Possible to add an element to a .NET Dictionary skipping the internal ContainsKey() call

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, base-class-library

I know about `Dictionary<K,V>.TryAdd()` method added in .NET Core 2.0 that improves performance by checking only once if the dictionary contains the key before adding the element unlike in:

```
if(!dico.ContainsKey(key)) { dico.Add(key,val); } // .Add() calls ContainsKey() a second time
```

However for performance reason I'd like to lazy build `val` only if `!dico.ContainsKey(key)`:

```
if(!dico.ContainsKey(key)) { dico.Add(key, new Value()); }
```

In this situation `TryAdd()` degrades performance since the value is not lazy built.

```
dico.TryAdd(key,new Value());
```

Is there a way to both have a single `ContainsKey()` call **AND** lazy build the value? Something like `AddWithNoContainsKeyCheck()`:

```
if(!dico.ContainsKey(key)) { dico.AddWithNoContainsKeyCheck(key, new Value()); }
```

Comment: not performance wise, Lazy<T> is a class, so an object gets created even if not needed, creating my own StructLazy<T> sounds wiser

Comment: `dico[key] = new Value();` maybe. It should not do the check but the overwriting behavior might have its own performance penalty but as you check before does not do anything wrong.

Comment: Looking at the source i might be wrong.

Comment: @Ralf but then new Value() is called anyway

Comment: I don't know if it is of any use, but you could cash the created value and use `TryAdd`. If adding was successful then delete the cash else re-use it next time you are adding.

Comment: Thanks @OlivierJacot-Descombes but a cache is typically implemented with a dictionary...

Comment: You need to cache only one single value in a field. `private static Value? _value;` and then `_value ??= new Value(); if(dict.TryAdd(key, _value) { _value = null; }`. You may also have to set the properties of the value which I have not shown here.

Comment: `if(!dico.ContainsKey(key)) { dico[key] = new Value(); }` Where is it called anyway?

Comment: Why not just create your own `TryAdd` which will accept the `Func<V>` or `Lazy<V>` instead of `V`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, by using the advanced API [`CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.getvaluereforadddefault), available from .NET 6 and later:

```
/// <summary>
/// Uses the specified function to add a key/value pair to the dictionary,
/// if the key does not already exist.
/// </summary>
public static bool TryAdd<TKey, TValue>(
    this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
    TKey key,
    Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory,
    out TValue value) where TKey : notnull
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(dictionary);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(valueFactory);

    ref TValue valueRef = ref CollectionsMarshal
        .GetValueRefOrAddDefault(dictionary, key, out bool exists);
    if (!exists)
    {
        try { valueRef = valueFactory(key); }
        catch { dictionary.Remove(key); throw; }
        value = valueRef;
        return true;
    }
    value = valueRef; // It was `value = default` in the original answer
    return false;
}
```

The `CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault` returns a [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#97-reference-variables-and-returns) to the value stored in the dictionary. In case the `valueFactory` fails, it is important to remove the newly added key. Otherwise a key with a `default(TValue)` will be inadvertently added in the dictionary.

**Note:** The extension method `TryAdd` in this answer offers the same functionality with the more convenient and more fluent [`GetOrAdd`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408916/find-or-insert-with-only-one-lookup-in-c-sharp-dictionary/74957779#74957779). The `bool` return value (conveying the information if the value was created or already existed) is rarely needed in practice.

Comment: If you store the result of invoking `valueFactory` into a local you can assign it to the ref local only if it didn't throw, and then not need to remove from the value that shouldn't have been added to the dictionary to begin with.  That you need to assign the value to `value` anyway means you don't even need to add a new variable, just change the order of how you use the ones you already have.

Comment: Also you might as well have `value` be the existing value if it already exists, making this method be an effective `GetOrAdd` since it would cost basically nothing to do so and adds some utility.

Comment: @Servy the OP wants to avoid calling the `valueFactory` in case the key already exists in the dictionary.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias _"wants to avoid calling the valueFactory..."_ - tbh no need to use `CollectionsMarshal` just custom `TryAdd` overload with `ContainsKey` check should be sufficient (also no need to try/catch-remove in this case).

Comment: Also should not be better change `value = default;` to `value = valueRef` for case when value is present?

Comment: @Servy regarding your second comment, you are right. The `TryAdd` in this answer is a less useful version of the non-existing [`GetOrAdd`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/15059 "Propose Adding a GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory) to Dictionary<TKey, TValue>").

Comment: @GuruStron the `CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault` allows to complete the operation with a single hashing of the `key`, in the common case that the `valueFactory` is successful.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias in general I agree but TBH I would go with ease of implementation and readability in general case unless I was putting this into the framework code itself =)

Comment: @GuruStron Microsoft agrees with you. They have [intentionally](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27062#issuecomment-880601478 "Developers can use CollectionsMarshal ref accessors for Dictionary<TKey, TValue> -- jkotas commented on Jul 15, 2021") made the `CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault` API not easily discoverable.

Comment: @GuruStron btw [the purpose](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/82999#issuecomment-1456713206 "Add CollectionsMarshal support for the Stack<T> collection -- tannergooding commented on Mar 6, 2023") of the `CollectionMarshal` is to provide primitive APIs that allow broader or more general APIs to be built by the .NET community, without needing to come back to Microsoft and ask for a new instance method each time.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I'm not suggest you call the value factory when the key exists.  Merely that you call valuefactory where you are, but assign the result to `value` and not `valueRef`, and then assign the value from `value` to `valueRef` on the next line, so that if there is an exception invoking `valueFactory` you never assign anything to `valueRef` and thus need to remove an item from the dictionary (which is not only expensive relative to the operations being performed, but risks the dictionary being in an invalid state, at least temporarily.

Comment: By re-odering those two lines you not only avoid putting the dictionary into an invalid state (hopefully temporarily) and performing the somewhat more expensive remove, but the refactor allows you to avoid the try/catch entirely, both simplifying the code and removing an expensive exception handler.

Comment: @Servy I am not sure that I understand your suggestion. Could you code it on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PvUQ0a) and post a link?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias https://dotnetfiddle.net/q09ine

Comment: @Servy [it doesn't work correctly](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ls8IuM). In case of failure a default value is added in the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.getvaluereforadddefault?view=net-7.0) to do this, like so:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var d = new Dictionary<int, Test>();

        ref Test? element = ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault(d, key:0, out bool exists);

        if (!exists)
        {
            element = new Test(42);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(d[0].Value); // Prints "42"
    }
}

public sealed class Test
{
    public Test(int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Creating Test with value = {value}");
        Value = value;
    }

    public int Value { get; }
}
```

This will add a `null` element which you must overwrite with the actual value after determining that the element did not previously exist.

Note that this is a bit dodgy because we've defined the dictionary as NOT containing any null values, but here we are temporarily inserting a null value (albeit one which is immediately overwritten with a non-null value). Some care and attention is required, especially if the `Test` constructor can throw.